# Suddenly all my elementor assets are stopped loading its showing the assets url not found

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

```
/wp-includes/css/dist/block-library/A.style.min.css,qver=6.2.2.pagespeed.cf.1qpRdvAQUt.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
wp-content/plugins/code-snippet-dm/public/css/A.main.min.css,qver=2.0.3.pagespeed.cf.xDvfW1x1_d.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
/wp-content/plugins/elementor/assets/css/A.frontend-legacy.min.css,qver=3.15.3.pagespeed.cf.6JKzv5N85-.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
/wp-content/plugins/elementor/assets/css/A.frontend.min.css,qver=3.15.3.pagespeed.cf.MYTctow7ep.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
/wp-content/plugins/elementor-pro/assets/css/A.frontend.min.css,qver=3.15.1.pagespeed.cf.6mpiH3rJYU.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
/wp-content/plugins/elementor/assets/lib/font-awesome/css/A.v4-shims.min.css,qver=3.15.3.pagespeed.cf.0XlImbwfpC.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
/wp-content/uploads/elementor/css/A.post-21020.css,qver=1694430275.pagespeed.cf.Swjvix9Ovb.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

I reinstalled my elementor and it was worked fine and again it stopped working.  Even I tried to regenerate the elementor css It doesn't help. this is the error I am facing.